# Gradle error while running flutter app in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

Anytime I try to run the default flutter app in android studio, I get an error saying this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\NAME\StudioProjects\first_app\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Jonat\StudioProjects\first_app\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Jonat\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\9jolsr12r2iru3ssdih8as3s3).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried searching for an answer but I did not find a solution. I decided to open my command prompt and type in Gradle and this is what I see,

[image: Comand error]

I don't know what to do or where to start since I am new to android studio. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

**UPDATE**

I went to the folder that was mentioned in the first error and all I needed to do was update the Gradle and it loaded everything. But now I'm receiving a new error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @77e838c

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

would anyone know how to go about this error?

Comment: From what the error says, you may have deleted by mistake a build.gradle file (or it's missing)

Comment: I have located the file and it's there, however, I can't find the scripts\9jolsr12r2iru3ssdih8as3s3 section. (taken from error first code)